# javascript create del row function button or chkbox

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a delete button to delete rows or using chkbox and button to delete rows. When I use the deleteRow function, it will delete all rows in the table. Also, I have assigned an element id to do other functions, so I cannot change the addrow function about assign element id.
When i use delete button, it can do i wanted. I want to delete the row when the checkbox checked How can i use checkbox to delete row  ?
Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="dataTable" class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Product ID:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productid" id="productid" class="form-control" /></td>
            <td align="center"><b>QTY:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="poqty" id="poqty" class="form- control"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" class="form-control" />
            <input type="button" value="del Item" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" class="btn btn-default" />

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="confirm">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div id="txtHint"></div>
        <div id="qty123"></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var y = 0;
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name = "chkbox";
        element1.id = "chkone" + y;
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox1[]";
        element2.id = "txtone" + y;

        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "text";
        element3.name = "txtbox2[]";
        element3.id = "txtre" + y;

        cell3.appendChild(element3);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        element4.type = "text";
        element4.name = "txtbox3[]";
        element4.id = "qtyone" + y;

        cell4.appendChild(element4);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element5 = document.createElement("input");
        element5.type = "text";
        element5.name = "txtbox4[]";
        element5.id = "txtra" + y;
        cell5.appendChild(element5);
        y++;

    }
</script>

<script>
    function deleteRow(dataTable) {

        var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);
        var row = document.getElementById(dataTable);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }

</script>
```

I want to delete the row when the checkbox checked , How can i use checkbox to delete row  ?

Comment: I think nobody would be mad at you if you format your code!

Comment: Your html is invalid.

Comment: Can you describe the problem that you're having?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @alex the problems is deleteRow(dataTable) can not work what i wanted.

Comment: @Rizier123 I Have format my code

Answer (score 0):

There's probably more than one problem here, but what sticks out to me is this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="addRow(tableID)" class="form-control" />
```

It doesn't look like you're correctly passing `tableID` to this function, whereas you're correctly passing a parameter to the deleteRow() function.  Where is `tableID` in your code?

Given the code you've posted, nothing happens when you invoke addRow() because the function is never fired - `tableID` is undefined.

Comment: i am sorry to post a wrong html code , i was change to addRow('dataTable')

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do when you say that you want to "use a checkbox to delete a row".  Do you want the row to be deleted when the checkbox is checked?  Do you want to delete only the rows that have checked checkboxes when, say, the user pushes a button?  Can you edit your question to reflect the exact functionality you desire, and what you have tried in the way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: i want to delete the row when the checkbox is checked.